# Why apache spark save function with a folder contain multi sub-file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When save spark dataframe, spark save to multi file inside a folder instead only one file.

```
df.write.format("json") \
                .option("header", "true") \
                .save('data.json', mode='append')
```

When run this code, **data.json** will be folder name instead file name.

And I want to know what are the advantages for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the dataframe or rdd the spark uses HadoopAPI underneath

The actual data that contains result is in the `part-` files which are created as the same number of partition on dataframe. If you have `n` numbers of `partition` then it creates `n` number of part files.

The main advantage of multiple `part` file is that if you have multiple workers can access and write the file in parallel.

Other files like `_SUCCESS` is to indicate that it has completed successfully and `.crc` is for the ckeck.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. But i how can workers access these files? For example: worker1 current working with part-00000, how worker2 know part-00000 are using by worker1 and choose another part

Comment: That is maintained by the driver, however the multiple parts also can be stored in the workes.